# Merging Pandas-File with OSMNX

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I want to find out which is the most dangerous road in Switzerland based on accidents that are happening there.
I have a csv-file with geolocations where each row is an accident and contains information on type of accident, people involved, date, geolocation (which I managed to transform into EPSG:4326) and more. I made some quantitative analysis with the file, all good.

But I now need to put those coordinates on a map to do further calculations. I want to use OSMNX for that with the city of Lucerne for testing purposes.
`G = ox.graph_from_place('Luzern, Switzerland', network_type='drive')`

But I have no idea how to add my accident-file to that map. And no idea how to search for it. ("merging Pandas file with OSMNX" or similar questions are not the right way to ask that question).

After I've done that, I will be able to use some OSMNX-functions (like nearest_edges) to determine what I want to know. But first I need to merge those two files. Can someone tell me what code I have to use?

I don't know if I've given sufficient information but of course will provide more if you tell me what you need.

I'm using Jupiter Notebook 6.3.0 on Mac (OS Big Sur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- used Swiss accident data
- have used two *merge* techniques between accident data and **OSMNX** data

  1. scoped data using a polygon of a city.  Used `sjoin()` for this
  2. located *bad* roads by using `sjoin_nearest()` to find indexes of *LineString* of road with relationship to the location of an accident
- have then visualised all of this as layers on a **folium** map

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import osmnx as ox
import folium
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

url = "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.astra.unfaelle-personenschaeden_alle/unfaelle-personenschaeden_alle/unfaelle-personenschaeden_alle_2056.csv.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(url.split("/")[-1])
if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(
        url,
        stream=True,
    )
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)

df_acc = [
    pd.read_csv(ZipFile(f).open(zf))
    for zf in ZipFile(f).infolist()
    if zf.filename.split(".")[-1] == "csv"
][0]
df_acc = df_acc.loc[
    :, [c for c in df_acc.columns if c.split("_")[-1] not in ["it", "de", "fr"]]
]
gdf_acc = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_acc,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
        df_acc["AccidentLocation_CHLV95_E"], df_acc["AccidentLocation_CHLV95_N"]
    ),
    crs="EPSG:2056",
).to_crs("epsg:4326")


# get OSM data for investigated location
G = ox.graph_from_place("Luzern, Switzerland", network_type="drive")
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G)

# get bounding polygon of investigated location
gdf_poly = ox.geocode_to_gdf({"city": "Luzern"}).loc[:, ["geometry", "display_name"]]

# reduce accidents down to those in investigated location
gdf_loc = gdf_acc.sjoin(gdf_poly)

# get roads with accidents
gdf_edges2 = gdf_edges.reset_index(drop=True).loc[:, ["name", "geometry"]]
gdf_bad_roads = gdf_edges2.loc[
    gdf_loc.loc[:, ["geometry", "display_name"]]
    .sjoin_nearest(gdf_edges2)["index_right"]
    .unique()
]


# now let's visualize what we have
m = gdf_poly.explore(
    name="Boundary",
    color="blue",
    style_kwds={"fillOpacity": 0.1},
    height=300,
    width=500,
)
m = gdf_edges.explore(name="Roads", m=m)
m = gdf_bad_roads.explore(name="Bad Roads", m=m, color="yellow")
m = gdf_loc.explore(name="Accidents", m=m, color="red")
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

#### osmnx nearest_edges()

- this really does same as first solution.  First solution uses **geopandas** `sjoin_nearest()`
- have not benchmarked performance, both will be using **rtree** and spatial indexes
- have played a bit will analysis, to aggregate based on same *edge* being associated with same edge to color edges

```
# project graph and points
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
gdf_loc_p = gdf_loc["geometry"].to_crs(G_proj.graph["crs"])

ne, d = ox.nearest_edges(
    G_proj, X=gdf_loc_p.x.values, Y=gdf_loc_p.y.values, return_dist=True
)

# reindex points based on results from nearest_edges
gdf_loc = (
    gdf_loc.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ne, names=["u", "v", "key"]))
    .assign(distance=d)
    .sort_index()
)

# join geometry from edges back to points
# aggregate so have number of accidents on each edge
gdf_bad_roads = (
    gdf_edges.join(gdf_loc, rsuffix="_loc", how="inner")
    .groupby(["u", "v", "key"])
    .agg(geometry=("geometry", "first"), number=("osmid", "size"))
    .set_crs(gdf_edges.crs)
)
# categorise edges based on number of accidents
gdf_bad_roads["cat"] = pd.qcut(gdf_bad_roads["number"], q=2, labels=["low", "high"])

m = gdf_poly.explore(
    name="Boundary",
    color="blue",
    style_kwds={"fillOpacity": 0.1},
    height=300,
    width=500,
)
m = gdf_bad_roads.explore(
    m=m, column="cat", cmap=["yellow", "red"], name="Accident roads"
)
m = gdf_loc.explore(name="Accidents", m=m, color="red")
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

Comment: ok - is data you are working with publicly available?  I can change answer if you can provide a link.  my understanding was you were trying to merge accident data with road data,  which is the example that I have provided.  just different location and accident data

Comment: Sorry I didn't know if I have to use comment or "add another answer .-." did the later now since I can format there.

Comment: updated.  BTW it's normal to edit your question with more details rather than posting and answer with more details....

Comment: Ah ok, thank your for the remark. And thank you so much for your help and time! It's invaluable :) I have some error messages with your code but will ask a new question since it's another problem.

Comment: you haven't accepted this answer yet.... so happy to look into it.  I think it should work in your environment without errors (it was intention).  I did restart my kernel multiple times to make sure it works...  `G` is setup in first code block,  so first code block has to be run before second code block

Comment: Oh shut didnt know I had to accept it haha. sorry! wanted to rate before but didn't know how either. Anyway, posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592793/geodataframe-value-error-data-should-be-a-1-dimensional-array-of-geometry-obj

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your answer Rob. Now those two files are merged, so nice :) And i visualised the data from the swiss city Lucerne and that looks good therefore I guess I did your steps correctly: [Plotting Accidents Lucerne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdBB6.jpg)

But I tried now for several hours and still don't know how I can use that data to do my calculations.
The Swiss accidents can be found here btw.: https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.astra.unfaelle-personenschaeden_alle/ (I'm editing them into the first post as well).

I looked around and found the function nearest_edges [in this answer] which looks like what I need [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766922/find-nearest-road-and-distance-to-it-for-a-point) but don't know what to do with it :/
I read the documentation but when trying this

```
#get a street network and randomly sample 10,000 points, from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766922/find-nearest-road-and-distance-to-it-for-a-point
G = ox.graph_from_place('Lucerne, Switzerland', network_type='drive')
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
points = gdf_acc(ox.get_undirected(G_proj), 10000)

%time ne1 = ox.nearest_edges(G_proj, X=points.x, Y=.y, return_dist=True)
# wall time: 2.91 s

%time ne2 = ox.nearest_edges(G_proj, X=points.x, Y=points.y, interpolate=10, return_dist=True)
# wall time: 302 ms
```

I get this error message

```
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jy/1f2tlvb965g30zhw9q3cvdw07r5rb_/T/ipykernel_74128/4210512587.py in <module>
      2 G = ox.graph_from_place('Lucerne, Switzerland', network_type='drive')
      3 G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
----> 4 points = gdf_acc(ox.get_undirected(G_proj), 10000)
      5 
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('time', 'ne1 = ox.nearest_edges(G_proj, X=points.x, Y=.y, return_dist=True)')

TypeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable`
```

Therefore, I'm doing something completely wrong but don't know what it is :)
Maybe I'm phrasing it all wrong...My goal is to make a list of roads where most accidents in Switzerland happened (using Lucerne as a test-object). I can do that with visualizing and counting but I'd rather do that with code because then I can check all kind of things (most accidents happened with a bike, street where accidents increased the most over time, puting accidents and traffic circulation in perspective,..). I asked GIS people and they told me the best way to do that is finding which is the nearest street from an accident and do that with every point. And then I can just do quantitative analysis with that list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).