# GeoDataFrame Value Error: 'data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects'

Tags: python, data-science, osmnx

I want to quantify some geolocations with osmnx using the nearest_edges-function. I get a value error message when running this code and don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
# project graph and points
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
gdf_loc_p = gdf_loc["geometry"].to_crs(G_proj.graph["crs"])

ne, d = ox.nearest_edges(
    G_proj, X=gdf_loc_p.x.values, Y=gdf_loc_p.y.values, return_dist=True
)

# reindex points based on results from nearest_edges
gdf_loc = (
    gdf_loc.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ne, names=["u", "v", "key"]))
    .assign(distance=d)
    .sort_index()
)

# join geometry from edges back to points
# aggregate so have number of accidents on each edge
gdf_bad_roads = (
    gdf_edges.join(gdf_loc, rsuffix="_loc", how="inner")
    .groupby(["u", "v", "key"])
    .agg(geometry = ("geometry", "first"), number=("osmid", "size"))
    .set_crs(gdf_edges.crs)
)
```

When running it tells me in the line .agg(geometry)`# we require a list, but not a 'str'` and from there on couple more issues leading to a value error `data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects`. I attached the whole Traceback. Thanks for your help!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jy/1f2tlvb965g30zhw9q3cvdw07r5rb_/T/ipykernel_82991/3621029527.py in <module>
      2 # aggregate so have number of accidents on each edge
      3 gdf_bad_roads = (
----> 4     gdf_edges.join(gdf_loc, rsuffix="_loc", how="inner")
      5     .groupby(["u", "v", "key"])
      6     .agg(geometry = ("geometry", "first"), number=("osmid", "size"))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    977 
    978         op = GroupByApply(self, func, args, kwargs)
--> 979         result = op.agg()
    980         if not is_dict_like(func) and result is not None:
    981             return result

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg(self)
    159 
    160         if is_dict_like(arg):
--> 161             return self.agg_dict_like()
    162         elif is_list_like(arg):
    163             # we require a list, but not a 'str'

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg_dict_like(self)
    457 
    458             axis = 0 if isinstance(obj, ABCSeries) else 1
--> 459             result = concat(
    460                 {k: results[k] for k in keys_to_use}, axis=axis, keys=keys_to_use
    461             )

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    305     )
    306 
--> 307     return op.get_result()
    308 
    309 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in get_result(self)
    537 
    538             cons = sample._constructor
--> 539             return cons(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="concat")
    540 
    541     def _get_result_dim(self) -> int:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    155             try:
    156                 if (
--> 157                     hasattr(self["geometry"].values, "crs")
    158                     and self["geometry"].values.crs
    159                     and crs

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1325         GeoDataFrame.
   1326         """
-> 1327         result = super().__getitem__(key)
   1328         geo_col = self._geometry_column_name
   1329         if isinstance(result, Series) and isinstance(result.dtype, GeometryDtype):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3424             if self.columns.is_unique and key in self.columns:
   3425                 if isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):
-> 3426                     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   3427                 return self._get_item_cache(key)
   3428 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_multilevel(self, key)
   3511             result_columns = maybe_droplevels(new_columns, key)
   3512             if self._is_mixed_type:
-> 3513                 result = self.reindex(columns=new_columns)
   3514                 result.columns = result_columns
   3515             else:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    322         @wraps(func)
    323         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 324             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325 
    326         kind = inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4770         kwargs.pop("axis", None)
   4771         kwargs.pop("labels", None)
-> 4772         return super().reindex(**kwargs)
   4773 
   4774     @deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments(version=None, allowed_args=["self", "labels"])

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4816 
   4817         # perform the reindex on the axes
-> 4818         return self._reindex_axes(
   4819             axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
   4820         ).__finalize__(self, method="reindex")

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   4589         columns = axes["columns"]
   4590         if columns is not None:
-> 4591             frame = frame._reindex_columns(
   4592                 columns, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance
   4593             )

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _reindex_columns(self, new_columns, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   4634             new_columns, method=method, level=level, limit=limit, tolerance=tolerance
   4635         )
-> 4636         return self._reindex_with_indexers(
   4637             {1: [new_columns, indexer]},
   4638             copy=copy,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   4895             new_data = new_data.copy()
   4896 
-> 4897         return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   4898 
   4899     def filter(

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    162                     _crs_mismatch_warning()
    163                     # TODO: raise error in 0.9 or 0.10.
--> 164                 self["geometry"] = _ensure_geometry(self["geometry"].values, crs)
    165             except TypeError:
    166                 pass

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in _ensure_geometry(data, crs)
     44             return GeoSeries(out, index=data.index, name=data.name)
     45         else:
---> 46             out = from_shapely(data, crs=crs)
     47             return out
     48 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in from_shapely(data, crs)
    149 
    150     """
--> 151     return GeometryArray(vectorized.from_shapely(data), crs=crs)
    152 
    153 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in __init__(self, data, crs)
    278             )
    279         elif not data.ndim == 1:
--> 280             raise ValueError(
    281                 "'data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects."
    282             )

ValueError: 'data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects.
```

**Edit:** thank you! Unfortunately it doesnt work. I downgraded Python to 3.9 (and upgraded Panda to 1.4 but have same issue). I added the Traceback of the other code as well.

```
----
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 gdf_bad_roads = gdf_edges.join(gdf_loc, rsuffix="_loc", how="inner")
      3 # aggregate so have number of accidents on each edge
----> 4 gdf_bad_roads_agg = gdf_bad_roads.groupby(["u", "v", "key"]).agg(
      5     geometry=("geometry", "first"), number=("osmid", "size")
      6 ).set_crs(gdf_edges.crs)
      8 print(f"""
      9 pandas: {pd.__version__}
     10 geopandas: {gpd.__version__}
     11 osmnx: {ox.__version__}""")

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py:869, in DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    866 func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
    868 op = GroupByApply(self, func, args, kwargs)
--> 869 result = op.agg()
    870 if not is_dict_like(func) and result is not None:
    871     return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:168, in Apply.agg(self)
    165     return self.apply_str()
    167 if is_dict_like(arg):
--> 168     return self.agg_dict_like()
    169 elif is_list_like(arg):
    170     # we require a list, but not a 'str'
    171     return self.agg_list_like()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:498, in Apply.agg_dict_like(self)
    495         keys_to_use = ktu
    497     axis = 0 if isinstance(obj, ABCSeries) else 1
--> 498     result = concat(
    499         {k: results[k] for k in keys_to_use}, axis=axis, keys=keys_to_use
    500     )
    501 elif any(is_ndframe):
    502     # There is a mix of NDFrames and scalars
    503     raise ValueError(
    504         "cannot perform both aggregation "
    505         "and transformation operations "
    506         "simultaneously"
    507     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:359, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    155 """
    156 Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic
    157 along the other axes.
   (...)
    344 ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    345 """
    346 op = _Concatenator(
    347     objs,
    348     axis=axis,
   (...)
    356     sort=sort,
    357 )
--> 359 return op.get_result()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:599, in _Concatenator.get_result(self)
    596     new_data._consolidate_inplace()
    598 cons = sample._constructor
--> 599 return cons(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="concat")

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:157, in GeoDataFrame.__init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    154 index = self.index
    155 try:
    156     if (
--> 157         hasattr(self["geometry"].values, "crs")
    158         and self["geometry"].values.crs
    159         and crs
    160         and not self["geometry"].values.crs == crs
    161     ):
    162         _crs_mismatch_warning()
    163         # TODO: raise error in 0.9 or 0.10.

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:1327, in GeoDataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   1321 def __getitem__(self, key):
   1322     """
   1323     If the result is a column containing only 'geometry', return a
   1324     GeoSeries. If it's a DataFrame with a 'geometry' column, return a
   1325     GeoDataFrame.
   1326     """
-> 1327     result = super().__getitem__(key)
   1328     geo_col = self._geometry_column_name
   1329     if isinstance(result, Series) and isinstance(result.dtype, GeometryDtype):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3473, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3471     if self.columns.is_unique and key in self.columns:
   3472         if isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):
-> 3473             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   3474         return self._get_item_cache(key)
   3476 # Do we have a slicer (on rows)?

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3560, in DataFrame._getitem_multilevel(self, key)
   3558 result_columns = maybe_droplevels(new_columns, key)
   3559 if self._is_mixed_type:
-> 3560     result = self.reindex(columns=new_columns)
   3561     result.columns = result_columns
   3562 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:324, in rewrite_axis_style_signature.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    322 @wraps(func)
    323 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 324     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4798, in DataFrame.reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4796 kwargs.pop("axis", None)
   4797 kwargs.pop("labels", None)
-> 4798 return super().reindex(**kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:4974, in NDFrame.reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4971     return self._reindex_multi(axes, copy, fill_value)
   4973 # perform the reindex on the axes
-> 4974 return self._reindex_axes(
   4975     axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
   4976 ).__finalize__(self, method="reindex")

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4611, in DataFrame._reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   4609 columns = axes["columns"]
   4610 if columns is not None:
-> 4611     frame = frame._reindex_columns(
   4612         columns, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance
   4613     )
   4615 index = axes["index"]
   4616 if index is not None:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4656, in DataFrame._reindex_columns(self, new_columns, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   4643 def _reindex_columns(
   4644     self,
   4645     new_columns,
   (...)
   4651     tolerance=None,
   4652 ):
   4653     new_columns, indexer = self.columns.reindex(
   4654         new_columns, method=method, level=level, limit=limit, tolerance=tolerance
   4655     )
-> 4656     return self._reindex_with_indexers(
   4657         {1: [new_columns, indexer]},
   4658         copy=copy,
   4659         fill_value=fill_value,
   4660         allow_dups=False,
   4661     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5054, in NDFrame._reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   5051 if copy and new_data is self._mgr:
   5052     new_data = new_data.copy()
-> 5054 return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:164, in GeoDataFrame.__init__(self, data, geometry, crs, *args, **kwargs)
    162         _crs_mismatch_warning()
    163         # TODO: raise error in 0.9 or 0.10.
--> 164     self["geometry"] = _ensure_geometry(self["geometry"].values, crs)
    165 except TypeError:
    166     pass

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:46, in _ensure_geometry(data, crs)
     44     return GeoSeries(out, index=data.index, name=data.name)
     45 else:
---> 46     out = from_shapely(data, crs=crs)
     47     return out

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/array.py:151, in from_shapely(data, crs)
    135 def from_shapely(data, crs=None):
    136     """
    137     Convert a list or array of shapely objects to a GeometryArray.
    138 
   (...)
    149 
    150     """
--> 151     return GeometryArray(vectorized.from_shapely(data), crs=crs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyproj_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/array.py:280, in GeometryArray.__init__(self, data, crs)
    275     raise TypeError(
    276         "'data' should be array of geometry objects. Use from_shapely, "
    277         "from_wkb, from_wkt functions to construct a GeometryArray."
    278     )
    279 elif not data.ndim == 1:
--> 280     raise ValueError(
    281         "'data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects."
    282     )
    283 self.data = data
    285 self._crs = None

ValueError: 'data' should be a 1-dimensional array of geometry objects.
```

```
pandas: 1.4.1
geopandas: 0.10.2
osmnx: 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have changed this to a MWE
- have separated out `join()` and `groupby()` / `agg()`
- have included versions
- one difference I can see - **python** 3.9 vs 3.10

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """AccidentUID,AccidentLocation_CHLV95_E,AccidentLocation_CHLV95_N
99BA5D383B96D02AE0430A865E33D02A,2663985,1213215
9B25C4871C909022E0430A865E339022,2666153,1211303
9B71AB601D948092E0430A865E338092,2666168,1211785
9C985CF7710A60C0E0430A865E3360C0,2663991,1213203
9EA9548660AB3002E0430A865E333002,2666231,1210786
9B2E8B25D5C29094E0430A865E339094,2666728,1210404
9C87C10FB73A905EE0430A865E33905E,2666220,1211811
9E30F39D35CA1058E0430A865E331058,2664599,1212960
9BC2EA43E0BFC068E0430A865E33C068,2665533,1212617
9C0BB9332AB30044E0430A865E330044,2666852,1211964"""
    )
)

gdf_loc = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data=df,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
        df["AccidentLocation_CHLV95_E"], df["AccidentLocation_CHLV95_N"]
    ),
    crs="EPSG:2056",
).to_crs("epsg:4326")

# get OSM data for investigated location
G = ox.graph_from_place("Luzern, Switzerland", network_type="drive")
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G_proj)

# project graph and points
gdf_loc_p = gdf_loc["geometry"].to_crs(G_proj.graph["crs"])

ne, d = ox.nearest_edges(
    G_proj, X=gdf_loc_p.x.values, Y=gdf_loc_p.y.values, return_dist=True
)

# reindex points based on results from nearest_edges
gdf_loc = (
    gdf_loc.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ne, names=["u", "v", "key"]))
    .assign(distance=d)
    .sort_index()
)

# join geometry from edges back to points
gdf_bad_roads = gdf_edges.join(gdf_loc, rsuffix="_loc", how="inner")
# aggregate so have number of accidents on each edge
gdf_bad_roads_agg = gdf_bad_roads.groupby(["u", "v", "key"]).agg(
    geometry=("geometry", "first"), number=("osmid", "size")
).set_crs(gdf_edges.crs)

print(f"""
pandas: {pd.__version__}
geopandas: {gpd.__version__}
osmnx: {ox.__version__}""")
```

```
pandas: 1.4.0
geopandas: 0.10.2
osmnx: 1.1.2
```

Alternative aggregate syntax.  Has been confirmed both work

- hence conclusion is that [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) are failing. Possibly should be raised as an issue on **pandas**, but is not failing on all environments
- `groupby()`/`apply()` is doing a **first** on shared edges and also necessary to set CRS again
- `dissolve()` is doing a **unary union** on geometries.  Conceptually should be the same, but is giving slightly different geometry. (A unary union of identical geometries IMHO is an instance of one of the geometries)

```
gdf_bad_roads.groupby(["u", "v", "key"]).agg({"geometry":"first", "AccidentUID":"size"}).set_crs(gdf_edges.crs).explore(color="blue")


gdf_bad_roads.dissolve(["u", "v", "key"], aggfunc={"AccidentUID":"size"}).explore(color="blue")
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly didn't work with new code and nython-version, traceback is edited on bottom of original post

Comment: you are getting the error when using just the sample data I included?  I'm suspecting a data issue however this won't be the case if the same data is being used...

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm getting it with my data but also with your sample data, i copy/pasted the whole code to test it

Comment: ok - not making much sense to me.  have updated answer with alternative syntax / methods for aggregate.  They are functionally slightly different.  If either / both work I'll explain

Comment: thank you! Yes, in fact they both work :)

Comment: great - have updated answer with more explanation - would appreciate if you accept / upvote this answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Accepted already (can't upvote yet), will read the explanation later :)

Comment: I'm so sorry but I have to ask more: I read it, tried it, works. But I'm not really sure, what you've done lol. 
gdf_loc gives me an X and a Y value for several accidents (sometimes more, sometimes less) with distance to this location: 47.05487/8.30095
1. No idea why it chose this location as center, do you?
2. How can I use those distances to quantify which streets are most dangerous? I see the plotting and realize those are those streets, but don't know how I can list them by name and number of accidents.

Comment: hmm, ok.  concepts really belong with first question.  `gdf_loc` is intended to be all accidents in Lucerne.  The accidents are points, not streets / roads. So to analyse dangerous roads need to associate accident points with roads.  These are edges (contained on OSMNX graph). so return from `nearest_edges()` is a tuple of index of edge and distance to edge (road).  The reason for re-indexing locations by nearest edges is so you can join edge attributes to location attributes and analyse using those attributes.

Comment: so I did something very simple, counted number of accidents on a given edge (BTW a road can have more that one edge, so this is a significantly simple approach)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me :) Now I can go on from here. Sorry for not asking the question correct in the first place  (to be able to do that you really need to know what you want/how to express it which obviously I wasn't capable of)